# Difference between two alias columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm sure this has been references before, but I have been looking all morning for a solution. I feel like there might be multiple ways of achieving this. All I need to do it subtract time_out - time_in or columns(T_0 - T_I). I have some extra columns in the code, but I was trying different things.

```
SELECT d.Sched_Time,
   d.Time_In,
   d.Time_Out,  
   TO_CHAR(d.Time_Out, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS T_O,
   TO_CHAR(d.Time_In, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS T_I,
   (d.Time_Out - d.Time_In) AS Units,
   TO_Timestamp(d.Time_Out, 'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') AS Nope,
   d.Activity_Desc,
   d.Sched_Duration
FROM Clients c
INNER JOIN DAILY_LOG_DATA d 
ON c.SHISID = d.SHISID
WHERE c.SHISID = 5019051
```

Here is the table:

[image]

When running this column:

```
TO_Timestamp(d.Time_Out, 'DD.MM.YYYY:HH24:MI:SS') AS Nope
```

It removes the times that I need to do my calculation.

When trying:

```
       TO_CHAR(d.Time_Out, 'HH24:MI:SS') - TO_CHAR(d.Time_In, 'HH24:MI:SS') AS T_I,
```

I get: SQL Error [1722] [22005]: [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01722: invalid number

Comment: What is the error that you are getting? or what is wrong with this code?

Comment: So what is your issue?  Realize that in oracle, subtracting a DATE from a DATE yields a number of _days_.  So in your first result row, time_in was 14:00, time_out was 14:45 of the same day, for a difference of 45 minutes, which is 0.03125 days - exactly what you got.

Comment: @EdStevens - How would I go about subtracting a TIME from a TIME? Or should I just calculate the 0.03125 days into 45 mins?

Comment: a minute is a day divided by 24 (hours) then divided by 60 (minute). So to go from a date fraction to minutes you need to multiply by 60*24. 
0.03125 * 60 * 24 = 45

Comment: @KoenLostrie - That makes sense. Thank you for the help.